# Infinitely iterable list class in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

[`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) is cool, but it has an internal "storage" that uses up memory. And I wanted to practice "tampering" with built-in methods of classes, which is a new field for me. I tried to implement a class which mostly behaves like a list, but when we try to iterate over it (with `for` loop, for example), it would jump back to the beginning when it reaches the end, therefore cycling indefinitely. Here's what I've come up with:

```
class InfiniteListEmptyError(Exception):
    pass


class InfiniteList(list):
    """
    Pretty much a regular list, but when iterated over, it does not stop in the end. 
    Instead, it iterates indefinitely.
    """

    def __init__(self, arg):
        super(InfiniteList, self).__init__(arg)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name == "it":
            # get iterator
            result = object.__getattribute__(self, name)
        else:
            try:
                result = super(InfiniteList, self).__getattribute__(name)
            except AttributeError:
                try:
                    result = self.it.__getattribute__(name)
                except AttributeError:
                    # Initialize iterator cuz it's not initialized
                    self.__iter__()
                    result = self.it.__getattribute__(name)
        return result

    def __iter__(self):
        it = super(InfiniteList, self).__iter__()
        self.it = it
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        try:
            result = next(self.it)
        except StopIteration:
            self.__iter__()
            try:
                result = next(self.it)
            except StopIteration:
                raise InfiniteListEmptyError("Could not iterate. List is empty!")

        return result

# TESTS

a = InfiniteList(tuple()) #empty list

print(a)
print(a.__length_hint__()) #testing iterator attributes
print(a.__eq__([1,3,5])) # false

# should raise exception, since the list is empty
try:
    for i in a:
        print(i)
except InfiniteListEmptyError:
    print("List is empty!")

a.append(1)
a.extend([3,5])
print(a)
print(a.__eq__([1,3,5])) #true

# infinite loop
for i in a:
    print(i)
```

It works fine, it does not store an auxiliary list, so it does not consume twice as much memory, like [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle). But I'm not sure about the possible caveats when it comes to handling attributes. And yeah, I had to implement iterator within the `InfiniteList` class itself, so I had to redirect the calls to iterator's methods (like `__length_hint__`) to the saved iterator `self.it`.

Comment: You know that by doing `a = list(range(50)); b = InfiniteList(a)` you are effectively copying your initial list, right? So what is the exact advantage over `itertools.cycle`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Simplifying the class

```
def __init__(self, arg):
    super(InfiniteList, self).__init__(arg)
```

Is unnecessary. Not only it doesn't add any value over the default constructor of lists (which accept any iterable to initialize a list from it) but it prevent from building an empty list by using a constructor without argument, such as `empty_list = list()`.

---

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    if name == "it":
        # get iterator
        result = object.__getattribute__(self, name)
    else:
        try:
            result = super(InfiniteList, self).__getattribute__(name)
        except AttributeError:
            try:
                result = self.it.__getattribute__(name)
            except AttributeError:
                # Initialize iterator cuz it's not initialized
                self.__iter__()
                result = self.it.__getattribute__(name)
    return result
```

Contrary to `__getattribute__`, `__getattr__` is only called if the lookup already failed. So you are assured that, if `self.it` has already been initialized, `__getattr__` won't be called to access it. You also don't really *need* to store the iterator directly. You know that, given the use cases of your class, `__getattr__` will most likely be called when trying to access an iterator method. You can thus build on that to create an iterator on demand and try to access its methods:

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    """Redirect missing attributes and methods to
    those of the underlying iterator.
    """
    iterator = super(InfiniteList, self).__iter__()
    return getattr(iterator, name)
```

---

```
def __iter__(self):
    it = super(InfiniteList, self).__iter__()
    self.it = it
    return self

def __next__(self):
    try:
        result = next(self.it)
    except StopIteration:
        self.__iter__()
        try:
            result = next(self.it)
        except StopIteration:
            raise InfiniteListEmptyError("Could not iterate. List is empty!")

    return result
```

Is overly complicated as implementing `__iter__` that returns `self` and having a `__next__` method can be simplified to turning `__iter__` into a generator most of the time:

```
def __iter__(self):
    if not self:
        raise InfiniteListEmptyError("Could not iterate. List is empty!")

    while True:
        iterator = super(InfiniteList, self).__iter__()
        yield from iterator
```

---

So the class can be defined as:

```
class InfiniteList(list):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        """Redirect missing attributes and methods to
        those of the underlying iterator.
        """
        iterator = super(InfiniteList, self).__iter__()
        return getattr(iterator, name)

    def __iter__(self):
        if not self:
            raise InfiniteListEmptyError("Could not iterate. List is empty!")

        while True:
            iterator = super(InfiniteList, self).__iter__()
            yield from iterator
```

## Differences with `itertools.cycle`

Building an `InfiniteList` out of an iterable *will* inevitably create memory to store the list and, as such, is no different from the memory used by `itertools.cycle`. Even building an `InfiniteList` out of an existing list will duplicate memory.

The only "advantage" being that you could build the list from scratch using `append` or `extend` and not use as much memory than `itertools.cycle`. However, such approaches are generally better handled using a list-comprehension or a generator expression. And feeding the generator expression to either `itertools.cycle` or `InfiniteList` will give the same memory footprint.

Except `itertools.cycle`:

1. is optimized in C;
2. doesn't consume the iterable upfront and, as such, can handle infinite generators (meaning `itertools.cycle(itertools.count())` is fine albeit unneccessary whereas `InfiniteList(itertools.count())` will eat up all your memory).

In short, unless you have a very specific use-case, most of the time your `InfiniteList` will have the exact same memory footprint than `itertool.cycle` with worse performances.

Answer (score 4):

This seems kind of complicated compared to something like this:

```
def cycle(seq):
    "Generator that yields the elements of a non-empty sequence cyclically."
    i = 0
    while True:
        yield seq[i]
        i = (i + 1) % len(seq)
```

Or, as Joe Wallis points out in comments:

```
def cycle(seq):
    "Generator that yields the elements of a non-empty sequence cyclically."
    while True:
        yield from seq
```

Comment: You can remove the need for the `i =` if you use `for item in seq: yield item` like `itertools.cycle` does. But nice answer